# How to get the latest lambda version in cloudformation yml?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I'm trying to reference an [edge lambda for cloudfront distribution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cloudfront-distribution-lambdafunctionassociation.html#cfn-cloudfront-distribution-lambdafunctionassociation-eventtype) in cloudformation.

What I have now is:

```
          LambdaFunctionARN:
            Fn::GetAtt: [BasicAuthLambdaFunction,Arn]
```

But I get this error:

> An error occurred: GGGCloudFrontDistribution - The function
>   ARN must reference a specific function version. (The ARN must end with
>   the version number.)

So.. is there some kind of technique to reference the latest version of the function?

Comment: In most cases, omitting the version number of a Lambda ARN implies "the latest version". I guess that's not allowed in this case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't use the latest version. You have to use a specific version as the documentation you linked states:

> You must specify the ARN of a function version; you can't specify a Lambda alias or $LATEST.

If you are creating the Lambda function in your template, you can also create a version and use that.

```
  BasicAuthLambdaFunctionVersion: 
    Type: "AWS::Lambda::Version"
    Properties:
      FunctionName:
        Ref: BasicAuthLambdaFunction
# ...
      LambdaFunctionARN:
        Fn::GetAtt: [BasicAuthLambdaFunctionVersion,Arn]
```

Note that when updating the stack, a new version will **not** be created when the Lambda function code changes. You have to manually create and use a new version by changing the name of `BasicAuthLambdaFunctionVersion` to `BasicAuthLambdaFunctionVersion2` or something else. To automate this, you can edit the template with a script before using it.

If you are using the Serverless Framework, take a look at:

https://github.com/silvermine/serverless-plugin-cloudfront-lambda-edge
https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/3944

Comment: I had to add ..
LambdaFunctionARN: !Join [':', [!GetAtt LambdaEdge.Arn, !GetAtt LambdaEdgeVersion.Version]]

Comment: The functionname can be the name of the function but also the function arn.

Comment: To get the ARN of a Function **Version**, use `Ref: BasicAuthLambdaFunctionVersion`. The above example of `Fn::GetAtt: [BasicAuthLambdaFunctionVersion,Arn]` will result in an error.  See [`AWS::Lambda::Version` Return values](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-version.html).