# AWS::Serverless::Function lambda version for Lambda@Edge event handler

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudfront, aws-sam

I am trying to use the AWS SAM framework to create a lambda to be used as a CloudFront event handler. It seems like the `AWS::Serverless::Function` doesn't support the `Version` attribute. The error I am seeing:

```
com.amazonaws.services.cloudfront.model.InvalidLambdaFunctionAssociationException: The function ARN must reference a specific function version. (The ARN must end with the version number.)
```

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48181038/1042151) that led me to try it. The relevant parts of my CloudFormation YAML file:

```
Resources:
  CloudFrontFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function 
    Properties:
      CodeUri: cloudfront-handler/hello_world/
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.7

Outputs:
  CloudFrontFunctionArn: 
      Description: CloudFront Function ARN with Version
      Value: !Join [':', [!GetAtt CloudFrontFunction.Arn, !GetAtt CloudFrontFunction.Version]]
```

When I `sam deploy` I get the following error.

```
Waiting for changeset to be created..
Error: Failed to create changeset for the stack: my-sam-app, ex: Waiter ChangeSetCreateComplete failed: Waiter encountered a terminal failure state Status: FAILED. Reason: Template error: resource CloudFrontFunction does not support attribute type Version in Fn::GetAtt
```

The properties available on `AWS::Lambda::Function` are [documented here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/AWS_Lambda.html) and it lists `Version` as one of the properties. So it seems `AWS::Serverless::Function` doesn't support getting the version. How can I get around this so I can deploy a CloudFront event handler implemented using the AWS SAM framework?

**UPDATE**

As per @mokugo-devops (thanks!), the fix for this was to add `AutoPublishAlias: live` like this:

```
Resources:
  CloudFrontFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function 
    Properties:
      CodeUri: cloudfront-handler/hello_world/
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.7
      AutoPublishAlias: live

Outputs:
  CloudFrontFunctionVersion: 
      Description: CloudFront Function ARN with Version
      Value: !Ref CloudFrontFunction.Version
```

Comment: Have you defined resource `AWS::Lambda::Version` as in the link you provided?  `AWS::Lambda::Version` is a separate resource from `AWS::Serverless::Function`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the function will not automatically have a Version deployed. Instead you will need to specify the `AutoPublishAlias` attribute.

More information available [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-specification-generated-resources-function.html#sam-specification-generated-resources-function-autopublishalias).

By doing this you will be unable to retrieve the version.

Instead you will need to create a resource of `AWS::Lambda::Version` and pass in the Arn from the `CloudFrontFunction` resource. Then you can get the Lambda version arn from this new resource and pass that to your `CloudFrontFunctionArn` output.